# Failed to install tesserocr for Tesseract v4 - MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tesseract, macos-mojave

I'm trying to pip install [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr)  but encountering the below error. 
I've tried a few different ways to install suggested on its doc, all of which with no avail.

At this point I'm certain the issue is not related to this package (since my friend installed it on the his Mac with no problems, I also installed on a Ubuntu VM w/o issue). 
The error seems to be c++ library since it cannot find headers  or  in Tesseract-OCR's source code (?), however before the error line it successfully finds .

I also have pytesseract installed w/o issue.

I'm hoping somebody here can help debug what's causing this issue.

My tesseract (installed through brew) version is: 
`tesseract 4.0.0
 leptonica-1.76.0
  libjpeg 9c : libpng 1.6.35 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11`

Thanks and let me know what other info you might need.

```
  Failed building wheel for tesserocr
  Running setup.py clean for tesserocr
Failed to build tesserocr
Installing collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/charlieyou/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/2h/ty244jbd1vd3d1l0m4k3_g980000gn/T/pip-install-wgh41bv0/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/2h/ty244jbd1vd3d1l0m4k3_g980000gn/T/pip-record-0grp17wc/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    pkg-config failed to find tesseract/lept libraries: b"Package tesseract was not found in the pkg-config search path.\nPerhaps you should add the directory containing `tesseract.pc'\nto the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable\nNo package 'tesseract' found\n"
    Supporting tesseract v4.0.0
    Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 262144}}
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'tesserocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/charlieyou/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/charlieyou/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/charlieyou/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/tesserocr.o -std=c++11 -DUSE_STD_NAMESPACE
    warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:603:
    **/usr/local/include/tesseract/unichar.h:24:10: fatal error: 'cstring' file not found
    #include <cstring>**
             ^~~~~~~~~
    1 warning and 1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my mac,

You should try install the package with conda :

### conda install -c mcs07 tesserocr

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score -1):

you can try : xcode-select --install

and I also can't install it , my error message is :
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

Comment: I already have that installed :) You should also post more details about the specific error.